# Refreshing dynamic form fields after data has changed

Tags: forms, coldfusion, datatables

I have a ColdFusion page that has, among other things, forms that are built using DataTables.

This page manages a handful of things (documents, categories, doctypes, etc) and each tab has CRUD functionality going on.

Initially, on each tab, it simply displays the current set of (fill in the blank) but if you click the create/update links/icons, the form to do so pops up. Some of the form fields are actually lists of the others. For example, if I want to upload a new document, one of the form fields is the category for that document.

I get the information for that form field by using cfinvoke to a get function in a cfc, which returns as a query and I loop through, populating the dropdown.

My problem is this: If I go and create a new category on the category tab I need the dropdown of category choices to update over on the new document form. However, it's already been populated and won't recheck that info until I refresh the page and thus won't show my new category in the dropdown.

The way I see it, I need to reinvoke the CFC method, repopulating the query variable and then refresh the form to make it loop through the new data and fully populate the dropdown.

I've tried to call the cfinvoke and reset the form from within the callbacks section of the DTHelper() but that (kind of as expected) didn't work.

How would I force the refreshing of the data, and subsequently, the form when this all takes place using AJAX and the actual page never reloads? Or should I just be forcing a page reload in this situation? (which works, I tried that, but it's a page refresh)

Comment: Put the part you need refreshed into a `<div>` and update that.

Comment: Thing is, I tried something similar. Didn't work. As I mentioned, refreshing even the whole form didn't help, since the field is being populated with a variable that, itself, has old data.

Answer (score 2):

So, my boss figured it out. You have to use `drawCallback()`.

In my example it worked like so. First, give all your major category select boxes a class:

```
<select name="majorCategoryID" class="major-category-select">
...
</select>
```

Then modify the DataTable options for major category:

```
majorcat_dt = $("#majorcat-dt").DataTable({
    ajax: "blah"
    columns: [{ blah }],
    drawCallback: function() {
        /* remove all options from select boxes */
        $(".major-category-select option").remove();

        /* this is the crazy DataTables api call to get rows */
        this.api().rows().data().each(function(row) {
            $(".major-category-select").append("<option value='"+row.id+"'>"+row.name+"</option>");
        });         
    }
});
```

This also removed the need for the `cfinvoke` in the first place since this also populates the dropdowns on page load as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did something like that once.

javascript:

```
var minutes = 10;
var refreshInterval = minutes * 60 * 1000;  // to get milliseconds

jQuery.fn.populateCensusDiv = function() {
$.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"censusData.cfc?method=getCensusData",
      cache:false,
      success: function(msg) {
      $("#census").html(msg);
      }
  });

setTimeout(function() {
$("#census").populateCensusDiv();

}, refreshInterval);

return this;
```

ColdFusion function

```
<cffunction name="getCensusData" access="remote" returntype="string" 
//deleted code
returnFormat = "plain">
<cfscript>
var returnString = "";
</cfscript>

more code
<cfsavecontent variable="returnString">
more code
</cfsavecontent>

<cfreturn returnString>
</cffunction>
```

My context was an html table that got refreshed every 10 minutes.  You can adapt it for your own needs.